# Different ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] per environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thin

For sake of a simple example, let's say I want to deploy my dev and test environments to different subfolders.  For example http://www.example.com/dev and http://www.example.com/test.

I'm using Thin, so I can easily set the relative path prefix by starting Thin with the following:

```
thin start --prefix /dev -e development
thin start --prefix /test -e test
```

However, my path helpers still generate paths that do not include the path prefix.  So I end up with something like `/images/logo.jpg` for both environments. I'd like to end up with `/dev/images/logo.jpg` and `/test/images/logo.jpg`.

I can hard-code something like this in my `config/environment.rb`

```
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/dev"
```

But that obviously doesn't dynamically associate the relative root with the environment.

Comment: If your subfolders had the same names as your environments could you just change the above to `ENV[RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT = "/#{Rails.env}"`? I'm not 100% sure Rails.env is defined at that point, though.

Comment: Looks like when run through Thin, ENV['RACK_ENV'] is available at that time.

Comment: Not sure how running Thin affects things, but just reading this, it seems RAILS_ENV should be available, and ActiveSupport is loaded, so Rails.env should work too (since RAILS_ENV is deprecated): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#rack-lib-rack-server-rb